# Java/Jsp programming quiz with respect to Big-O notation

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Question: Given: a list of integers (duplicates are allowed); and integer N. Remove the duplicates from the list and find the N-th largest element in the modified list. Implement at least two different solutions to find N-th largest element with O(N*log(N)) average time complexity in Big-O notation, where N is the number of elements in the list.

According to my understanding i can use Merge Sort, Heap Sort, Quick sort on the provided integer list with duplicates to find the N-th largest element with O(N*log(N)) average time complexity in Big-O notation. Is that correct ?

Also, what about duplicates in the list do i just add an extra line of code in the above mentioned algorithm to remove duplicates will that not affect the O(N*log(N)) average time complexity because Merge Sort, Heap Sort, Quick sort will only sort the list not delete duplicates.

I am not looking for any code but just tips and ideas about how to proceed with the question ? I am using Java  also is there any predefined classed/methods in java that i can use to accomplish the task rather than me coding Merge Sort, Heap Sort, Quick sort on my own.

My aim is to complete the task keeping in mind O(N*log(N)) average time complexity.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is homework.

Comment: There are too many different `N` in your question.

Comment: @Henry I think all of the N are the number of items in the list

Comment: @Thijser but there is also the N-th largest element.

Comment: I hope this clears the confusion .... List of integers: 5,9,5,2,3,1,4 N: 2.
When duplicates are removed, the list becomes 5,9,2,3,1,4 So, the answer is 5, because 5 is the 2-nd largest element in the modified list.

Comment: No, it doesn't clear up the confusion. To clear up the confusion you would have to actually substitute N with M where appropriate in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You first sort the list and then you remove illiterate over it to find all the duplicates. A second methode might be to loop over all elements and keep a tree structure in which for each element you first check if it's already present in the tree structure O(log(n)) and if is remove it else add it to the tree structure O(log(n)). This makes the whole algorithm O(n(log(n))).

Answer (score 0):

Since you added java as a tag:

```
List<Integer> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList(new TreeSet(originalList));
```

This will construct a new, sorted list without duplicates. Regarding time complexity, this adds up to O(n*log n) (the complexity of constructing a binary balanced tree with n elements). As a bonus, you can try and replace TreeSet with LinkedHashSet to preserve elements' order (among duplicates, I think the last one is kept).

About the last part, removing an element by index is straight forward afterwards.

Of course, if it is a homework question, you may need to implement your own red-black tree to get the same result.