# violating the given average time complexity in Big-O notation

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I am trying to Implement a solutions to find k-th largest element in a given integer list with duplicates with `O(N*log(N))` average time complexity in Big-O notation, where N is the number of elements in the list.

As per my understanding Merge-sort has an average time complexity of `O(N*log(N))` however in my below code I am actually using an extra for loop along with mergesort algorithm to delete duplicates which is definitely violating my rule of find k-th largest element with `O(N*log(N))`. How do I go about it by achieving my task  `O(N*log(N))` average time complexity in Big-O notation?

```
public class FindLargest {
    public static void nthLargeNumber(int[] arr, String nthElement) {
        mergeSort_srt(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        // remove duplicate elements logic
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[b] != arr[i]) {
                b++;
                arr[b] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        int bbb = Integer.parseInt(nthElement) - 1;
        // printing second highest number among given list
        System.out.println("Second highest number is::" + arr[b - bbb]);
    }

    public static void mergeSort_srt(int array[], int lo, int n) {
        int low = lo;
        int high = n;
        if (low >= high) {
            return;
        }

        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        mergeSort_srt(array, low, middle);
        mergeSort_srt(array, middle + 1, high);
        int end_low = middle;
        int start_high = middle + 1;
        while ((lo <= end_low) && (start_high <= high)) {
            if (array[low] < array[start_high]) {
                low++;
            } else {
                int Temp = array[start_high];
                for (int k = start_high - 1; k >= low; k--) {
                    array[k + 1] = array[k];
                }
                array[low] = Temp;
                low++;
                end_low++;
                start_high++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... str) {
        String nthElement = "2";
        int[] intArray = { 1, 9, 5, 7, 2, 5 };

        FindLargest.nthLargeNumber(intArray, nthElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the Nth largest of N items, sounds like you want the minimum.  Why not traverse the list, keeping track of the current minimum.  When you get to the end in O(N) time, you'll have the minimum.  Did you mean the k-th largest of N items?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: Your question is a bit confused. It's impossible to find the n'th largest element in O(n log n). Think about a list of 10 million elements and you want the 4'th largest. You're saying your algorithm's runtime should be governed by the 4, not the 10 million. You probably mean the k'th largest element in a list of length n.  Now do your sort, which requires O(n log n).  One more pass to find the k'th largest is only O(n), so overall run time is still  O(n log n).  Then note that with care you can reduce this to O(n) with @OliCharlesworth's suggestion.

Comment: my bad i mean the kth largest element i just updated my question

Comment: In addition to what's been said: merge sort (if implemented correctly) guarantees O(n log n) (it's the worst case, well also the average one). Walking through your list once more, doesn't change overall complexity, since: O(n + n log n) = O(n log n)

Comment: @SirRichie if i understood you correctly do you mean my above code still is within the range of   O(n log n) average time complexity ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, provided that your merge sort is in O(n log n), I didn't check that.

Comment: @SirRichie can you please take a quick look at my logic ?

Comment: It's hard to be sure by looking at code just like that. Create a list with say, a few million elements, run it through your merge sort and look at the time, it should be a good-enough method to test your assumption.

Comment: @Gene thank you i think you had the same point as SirRichie

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java/Jsp programming quiz with respect to Big-O notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918887/java-jsp-programming-quiz-with-respect-to-big-o-notation)

Comment: Your `mergeSort_srt` is not O(n log n) because you take more time as O(n) for one merge pass. A typical implementation would use two arrays and merge from one into the other so that you don't have to move elements around.

Comment: @Henry can you please link me to a typical implementation of merge sort if any so that i can compare?

Comment: @user3157309 see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem here is that you don't understand how to do the time analysis.  If you have one routine which takes O(n) and one which takes O(n*log(n)), running both takes a total of O(n*log(n)).  Thus your code runs in O(n*log(n)) like you want.

To do things formally, we would note that the definition of O() is as follows:
 f(x) ∈ O(g(x)) if and only if there exists values c > 0 and y such that f(x) < cg(x) whenever x > y.

Your merge sort is in O(n*log(n)) which tells us that its running time is bounded above by c1*n*log(n) when n > y1 for some c1,y1.  Your duplication elimination is in O(n) which tells us that its running time is bounded above by c2*n when n > y2 for some c2 and y2.  Using this, we can know that the total running time of the two is bounded above by c1*n*log(n)+c2*n when n > max(y1,y2).  We know that c1*n*log(n)+c2*n < c1*n*log(n)+c2*n*log(n) because log(n) > 1, and this, of course simplifies to (c1+c2)*n*log(n).  Thus, we can know that the running time of the two together is bounded above by (c1+c2)*n*log(n) when n > max(y1,y2) and thus, using c1+c2 as our c and max(y1,y2) as our y, we know that the running time of the two together is in O(n*log(n)).

Informally, you can just know that faster growing functions always dominate, so if one piece of code is O(n) and the second is O(n^2), the combination is O(n^2).  If one is O(log(n)) and the second is O(n), the combination is O(n).  If one is O(n^20) and the second is O(n^19.99), the combination is O(n^20).  If one is O(n^2000) and the second is O(2^n), the combination is O(2^n).

Comment: thanks for the explanation that helps .... Also, one quick question if i had to implement the same algorithm to find k-th largest element with average time complexity O(N) which algorithm should i use to code in java? I was looking at bubble sort but it has an average time complexity of O(n2)

Comment: You should probably look at the comments above because someone's already linked to the Wikipedia article on selection algorithms and it tells you about a O(N) selection algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is your merge routine where you have used another loop which i donot understand why, Hence i would say your algorithm of merge O(n^2) which changes your merge sort time to O(n^2).

Here is a pseudo code for typical O(N) merge routine :-

```
void merge(int low,int high,int arr[]) {


  int buff[high-low+1];
  int i = low;
  int mid = (low+high)/2;
  int j = mid +1;
  int k = 0;
  while(i<=mid && j<=high) {

      if(arr[i]<arr[j]) {
           buff[k++] = arr[i];
           i++;
      }
      else {
           buff[k++] = arr[j];
           j++;
      }
  }

  while(i<=mid) {
        buff[k++] = arr[i];
           i++;       
  }

    while(j<=high) {
        buff[k++] = arr[j];
           j++;       
  }


  for(int x=0;x<k;x++) {

       arr[low+x] = buff[x]; 
   }

}
```